# Natbib Bibliography as Appendix B in memoir class

Tags: bibliographies, memoir, appendices

I use memoir class and natbib for my book and want to make bibliography as an Appendix B.

The issue seems to be same as in [Adding bibliography to appendix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56397/adding-bibliography-to-appendix). The solution thereof (as showed below) is giving out exactly what I am seeking for, except for the fact that it uses *scrreprt* class, not *memoir* as mine.

Please kindly teach me any possible solution for this issue in memoir class?

```
\documentclass[10pt,DIV=12,a4paper,numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
  \makeatletter
    \renewcommand*\bib@heading{%
    \chapter{\bibname}%
    \@mkboth{\MakeMarkcase{\bibname}}{\MakeMarkcase{\bibname}}}%
  \makeatother
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents %% Adds table of content
  \chapter{Chapter 1}
  \chapter{Chapter 2}
  \appendix
    \chapter{Supplementary Information}
      \section{Tables}
      \section{Figures}
    \bibliographystyle{abbrv}
    \bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the equivalent redefinition within memoir would be:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@memb@bchap}{%
  \chapter{\bibname}%
  \bibmark
  \prebibhook}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents %% Adds table of content
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\chapter{Chapter 2}
\appendix
\chapter{Supplementary Information}
\section{Tables}
\section{Figures}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! It works. How could you get such magic? Please receive my appreciation.